# Disable the Google OTA updates completely

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

My android device is rooted and I would like to disable the Google OTA updates completely.

I did following steps:

1. Installed **Disable Services** and allowed it for root access.
2. Opened **Disable Services**
3. Under **System Apps**, selected **Google Services Framework**
4. I found **SystemUpdateService** is already unchecked.
5. I checked it and again unchecked it, then I restarted the android device.

However I see the notification for System Update. For its temporary resolution, I unchecked the notification of **Google Play Services**.

Please help me to disable the Google OTA updates completely

Regards
GNS

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's put in

settings > about phone > software updates > turn to manual updates only

Comment: Hi..there is no option to turn off software update manually in settings > about phone.